# 'ldd' reports 'not found' when looking for shared library

Tags: x86, g++, 64-bit, shared-libraries, ldd

I have two shared libraries, 'engine.so' and 'cengine.so'. 'cengine.so' has a dependency to 'engine.so', which is confirmed by the 'ldd'-command:

http://puu.sh/gj0ZU/f4530c3c28.jpg

However it states that it couldn't find the library, even though they're both in the same directory! Do I manually have to specify the lookup directories somehow?

Additionally, there's a dependency to 'ld-linux-x86-x64.so.2'. I've built the program as a 32bit application (Without the -m64 parameter), why is it automatically linking to a 64bit(I assume?) library?

Comment: Try exporting `LD_LIBRARYPATH=<path where libengine.so is present>` and then do `ĺdconfig`

Answer (score 1):

Export LD_LIBRARY_PATH to path where the .so file is present

```
$ export LD_LIBRARYPATH=~/Desktop/host/projects/weave/lib/
```

Then do ldd.

```
$ ldd libcengine.so
```

You built the program on 64 bit system without any explicit -m32/-m64 option, that will build default 64 bit binary right?